# Recharts, Change the background color of bar in bar graph on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bar-chart, recharts

Image of currently what is working

[image]

Image of what is required

[image]

Currently on hovering the graph the color is changing but when I am hovering above the bar the tooltip comes but my bar graph is not filling with the selected color. Is their a way to do that in recharts.
I am adding a code that will make it easy to understand. Thank you in advance.

```
const [activeBarIndex, setActiveBarIndex] = useState();

<ResponsiveContainer width={"100%"} height={400}>
    <ComposedChart
      data={data}
      barCategoryGap={0}
      margin={{
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20,
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeOpacity={0} />
      <XAxis dataKey="name" hide />
      <YAxis hide />
      <Tooltip
        active={false}
        viewBox={{ x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400 }}
        content={<CustomTooltip />}
      />
      {trancheLines[selectedLine ? 0 : 1]}
      {trancheLines[!selectedLine ? 0 : 1]}
      <Bar
        size={20}
        dataKey="barGraph"
        onMouseEnter={(_, index) => setActiveBarIndex(index)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setActiveBarIndex()}
        isAnimationActive={false}
      >
        {data.map((entry, index) => (
          <Cell
            cursor="pointer"
            fill={index === activeBarIndex ? primaryColor : secondaryColor}
            key={entry.id}
          />
        ))}
      </Bar>
    </ComposedChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Comment: Did you succeed ?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the answer is no because `primaryColor` for `Cell` will be applied only if `index === activeBarIndex` and `activeBarIndex` will be setted only on `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`.

**Experimental approcah (not tested):**

Let's start from the fact that when you hover something, `Tooltip` appears. Well, so we can use this event ot do some. The problem is that, as far as I can see, `Tooltip` does not have any `onShow` event ([Tooltip API](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip)).

The only thing that we could use is `active` property.

Well, if you add a ref to Tooltip:

```
const toolRef = useRef();
...
<Tooltip
        ref={toolRef}
        active={false}
        viewBox={{ x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400 }}
        content={<CustomTooltip />}
      />
...
```

you should be able to do something like:

```
if(toolRef.current.active) //then the Tooltip is active
```

If all of those conditions are true, if tooltip becames active, you could set the `activeBarIndex` solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am having the same problem. The fill property of the cell permits to change the color of the cell in the bar, but how to change the background of it, by default #ccc  like here : https://recharts.org/en-US/api/BarChart ?